# CSS Language Speak: Container vs Wrapper?

Tags: html, css

What's the difference between container and wrapper?  And what is meant by each?

Comment: let's assume you want to put some candies in a box. first you wrap individual candies (in wrappers) and then put all the candies (with wrappers around them) into the box (the container)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference between them.

It's just what you like to call the `<div>` that, often, contains all content of a page

Comment: @allesklar: Yep, that's better. Anyway, one of its functions is often to center all content

Comment: The second answer is superior to this one, in terms of disambiguation and differentiation (I'm a web dev); just my two cents.

Answer (score 206):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13202141/777071) answer:

> In programming languages the word **container** is generally used for
>   structures that can contain more than one element.
>
> A **wrapper** instead is something that wraps around a single object
>   to provide more functionalities and interfaces to it.

This definition matches with meaning of words and it's useful for HTML structures like:

```
<ul class="items-container">
    <li class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="item">...</div>
    </li>
    <li class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="item">...</div>
    </li>
    <li class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="item">...</div>
    </li>
    <li class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="item">...</div>
    </li>
    <li class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="item">...</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I like this way of thinking.

Comment: This makes sense to me.

Comment: I agree with this answer.

Comment: This should be the answer and not the other one which is a non-answer

Answer (score 5):

I like to throw in something here:

With current CSS standards and best practices, usually you have a container element that has the `display: grid` property. This `div` contains all the `columns` and `rows` of the layout. It also has a viewport wide `background` color, `border` and `shadow`. These properties are displayed using the entire width of the browser.

Now you need to add the content. You have to create another div, this a `max-width: 1256px` and now you give the `margin: 0 auto` and `width: 100%`.

So the structure will be:

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

This breaks the previous answer's logic of a `container` having many elements and a `wrapper` just one, but I've found this approach to be effective when building sections that have specific separate styling from other sections like shadows and borders.

**Therefore, in some situations:**

**A `container` is for styling the entire width of a section. A `wrapper` is for styling and centering the `max-width` content inside it.**

Comment: In that case, I would recommend to use more meaningful class names.

Comment: Agreed, the example above is for simplicity and to provide context to what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: These are both containers, the inner container just needs an additional class.

Answer (score 2):

There can be a difference, if you choose to give'em one. Actually it makes sense to have two names for a container/wrapper, as they have different functions:

1) the standard wrap we think of has a width of let's say 960px or 60em and centers its content on the screen (margin:auto)

2) there's another wrap - the one that is in some cases necessary to implement a sticky footer. imo the sticky footer with the best browser support (no js and at least quite clean) is this one: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

apropos sticky: sticking to existing naming conventions, I like the one of apppie, which clearly distinguishes between wrap 1 (called container) and wrap 2 (called wrapper). see: http://www.apppie.org/pages/approach/naming.html

there might be other conventions. as said, that you distinguish makes sense - how is up to you.