# Difference between container and wrapper

Tags: containers, wrapper

In a programming language (e.g. Java), what's the difference between `container` and `wrapper` (or is there a difference). I've heard both the terms used vaguely.

Comment: This might help to define wrapper at least: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In programming languages the word **container** is generally used for structures that can contain more than one element, for example a *Map*, a *Set* or a *List*. These structures normally provide methods like `contains`, that are semantically suitable if the object can contain more than one item.

A **wrapper** instead is something that wraps around a single object to provide more functionalities and interfaces to it. The typical example is the `Integer` class that in Java wraps the base type `int`.